# Add image to star pattern printing in python

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7, tkinter-canvas

How do I print this on GUI(Tkinter) so that I can add image to its background or is there any other way to add image to this program?
I have tried importing it on Tkinter but didn't know how to print this there

```
# List for the loop print star message
print_H=[[" " for i in range(6)]for j in range(6)]
print_A=[[" " for i in range(6)]for j in range(6)]
print_P=[[" " for i in range(6)]for j in range(6)]
print_Y=[[" " for i in range(6)]for j in range(6)]

# Loop for H "*" pattern 
for r in range(6):
    for c in range(6):
        if c == 0 or c == 5 or (r ==  3 and (c>0 and c <5)):
            print_H[r][c]="*"

# Loop for A "*" pattern
for r in range(6):
    for c in range(6):
        if ((c == 0 or c==5) and  r!=0)  or (r==0 and(c>0 and c<5)) or (r==3  and(c>0 and c<5)) :
            print_A[r][c]="*"

# Loop for P"*" pattern
for r in range(6):
    for c in range(6):
        if c==0 or (c==4 and (r==1 or r==2)) or ((r==0 or r==3) and (c>0 and c<4)) :
            print_P[r][c]="*"

# Loop for Y "*" pattern
for r in range(6):
    for c in range(6):
        if (c==2 and r>1) or (r==c and c<2) or (r==0 and c==4) or (r==1 and c==3) :
            print_Y[r][c]="*"

# This will print all star("*") in the message form       
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(6):
        print(print_H[i][j],end=" ")
    for j in range(6):
        print(print_A[i][j],end=" ")
    for j in range(6):
        print(print_P[i][j],end=" ")
    for j in range(6):
        print(print_P[i][j],end=" ")
    for j in range(6):
        print(print_Y[i][j],end=" ")
    print( )
```

Comment: Its one of the basic concepts of using `tkinter` using `Label` .

Answer (score 0):

So, if you want to put keyboard symbols in tkinter, you have a few options depending on what you want to do with them.

To get started, you need to add tkinter to your program and set up a window:

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

That will do it.  Seeing as you want to add an image to the background, I would recommend using a canvas for holding all your *s.  The following will let you do that:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

for i, j in ((1,1),(10,10),(50,10),(100,1),(100,100)):
    canvas.create_text(i, j, text="*", anchor='nw')

root.mainloop()
```

I just picked some random places to put the *s, you can put them where ever you like.  Replace the i and j in my example with the locations you want them.

After that, you can add images; I recommend you look up how PIL works to do that.  Also, seeing as you haven't gotten this far, maybe read up on tkinter's canvas tools as well.  You can learn all sorts of things by typing in "pythong tkinter canvas " in to your favorite search engine.

As I said, there are other ways to put text in a tkinter window.  Most notably, you could use the text widget or some label widgets.  Might I recommend you start reading through http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/ and see what you can learn.